# Google Nexus 4 weird sound problem

Tags: audio, nexus-4, hardware

Are there any solutions to the Google Nexus 4 weird sound problem? This is how it [sounds](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3mtVkJlDxvKWlpzY0VoNUpZYnM/edit).

Will Google replace the phone?

I am in Singapore and bought this phone through a friend in the US.

There is no proper support information for this phone from Google / LG. I tried calling '855-83-NEXUS' but they are closed for the day. I will try calling them tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from [vi.su.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/27182/vi-su) in comments (to make it clear for other users)

> Found out solution to this problem. In fact, this is not a problem at
>   all. NFC device in the nexus phones is the source for this sound. When
>   placed near a RFID / smartcard, it actually tries to read it aloud.
>   [Galaxy Nexus NFC Weirdness](http://youtube.com/watch?v=3emvuTgccFU)